# Android Studio equivalent of @RequestBody in Spring Boot Web

Tags: android, json, spring-boot

With Spring Boot Web, you can do this:

```
    /**
     * Defines a route to POST a new transaction
     * @param transaction the Transaction to POST
     * @return ResponseEntity<Boolean> Http.Status CREATED or INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
     */
    @PostMapping("transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> postTransaction(@RequestBody Transaction transaction){
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(service.postTransaction(transaction), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(false, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

In the code above, Transaction is my custom POJO class. RequestBody is the body of the POST and a JSON string representation of a Transaction object.

With just that, you get a POJO object constructed from a JSON string. Easy.

My question is whether there is an equivalent for my Android client making a GET request and receiving a POJO object as a JSON string in response.

Obviously, the POJO class would be defined in the Android client as well.  I know that I can use jackson or GSON to parse the JSON, manually, and construct the object, but it seems like there should be a common way of getting right to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use retfofit. It is one of the most used libraries for network requests in Android.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

Service:

```
public interface MyApiService {
    @GET("transactions/{transactionId}")
    Call<Transaction> getTransaction(@Path("transactionId") String transactionId);
}
```

There is no `transaction_id` in your example, but I added it to show you how you can use it.

Request sample:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("enter_base_url")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

MyApiService myApiService = retrofit.create(MyApiService.class);

Call<Transaction> call = myApiService.getTransaction("enter_transaction_id");
call.enqueue(new Callback<Transaction>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Transaction> call, Response<Transaction> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Transaction transaction = response.body();
            System.out.println(transaction + "");
        } else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Transaction> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

This line will parse the JSON for you.
`addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`